# How to check a List whether it contains all the elements as NULL string?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am having a `LinkedList` as -

```
List<String> tables = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Sometimes, `tables` list will look like, meaning it will have all the null string values inside it -

```
[null, null]
```

Is there any direct way of identifying if the `tables` list has all the elements as `null` string, then return true, otherwise return false.

One way I can think of is just keep on iterating it and see whether it has null string or not and then return true or false accordingly.

**UPDATE:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String table_1 = null;
String table_2 = "hello";
List<String> tables = new LinkedList<String>();
tables.add(table_1);
tables.add(table_2);

boolean ss = isAllNull(tables);
System.out.println(ss);
}

public static boolean isAllNull(Iterable<?> list) {
for (Object obj : list) {
    if (obj != null)
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: The way you think is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you are thinking is good, better if you make it as part of your utility class

```
public static boolean isAllNull(Iterable<?> list){
    for(Object obj : list){
        if(obj != null)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that this util accepts [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface for it to work in a wider scope.

Comment: Is there any benefit of having Iterable<?> or should we not pass List as it is and iterate it?

Comment: Yes, using `Iterable` instead `List` interface will make the this utility method to work with other `Iterable` implementations of type  `Set`, `Queue`, `Stack` etc. Its a util so better maximize polymorphism.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for tip. I have updated my question. Can you please check whether the way I am doing is correct or not? Just need a second eye..

Comment: Yes its correct. In the code you give it will return false since `table_2` is not `null`. If you set `table_2` as `null` then it will return true.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Guava library:

```
Iterables.all(input, Predicates.isNull());
```

With `static import` it will become even more readable:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.isNull;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.all;

Iterable<?> input = ...
all(input, isNull())
```

Answer (score 0):

You were correct that is the solution. You can check if there is any not null and return false at the first occurrence.

```
String table_1 = null;
String table_2 = null;
List<String> tables = new LinkedList<>();
tables.add(table_1);
tables.add(table_2);

for (String table : tables) {
    if (table != null)
    {System.out.println("False");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without 3rd party libraries:

```
Set set = new HashSet(tables);
boolean allNull = set.size() == 1 && set.iterator().next() == null;
```